# Override weblogic.xml configuration using deployment plan

Tags: deployment, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I've got following issue. I'm deploying my WAR application to multiple environments. Each environment has its own principal name that I want to supply to WAR using deployment plan. WAR app contains default user and weblogic.xml used to map role to principal is as follows:

```
...
<run-as-role-assignment>
   <role-name>sampleRole</role-name>
   <run-as-principal-name>defaultUser</run-as-principal-name>
</run-as-role-assignment>
...
```

Deployment plan used for subsitution of value in run-as-principal-name element is as follows:

```
<deployment-plan>
    ...
    <variable-definition>
        <variable>
            <name>runAsIdentity</name>
            <value>someEnvironmentSpecificUser</value>
        </variable>
    </variable-definition>
    <module-override>
        <module-descriptor external="false">
            <root-element>weblogic-web-app</root-element>
            <uri>WEB-INF/weblogic.xml</uri>
            ...
            <variable-assignment>
                <name>runAsIdentity</name>
                <xpath>/weblogic-web-app/run-as-role-assignment/run-as-principal-name</xpath>
                <operation>replace</operation>
            </variable-assignment>          
        </module-descriptor>
    </module-override>
</deployment-plan>
```

Principal defaultUser doesn't exist in my target environment but someEnvironmentSpecificUser does. However, I'm not able to override the value in weblogic.xml and sill getting following error during deployment:

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [HTTP:101256]The run-as user: defaultUser for the servlet: spring-ws for Web application: /sampleApp could not be resolved to a valid user in the system. Verify the user exists.
```

As I wrote above, user exists, xpath is correct, but override doesn't work. If I correct user in weblogic.xml and put there directly the replacement someEnvironmentSpecificUser, everything works well.

Does anybody have some idea why is this happening? Are there some limitations, e.g. that I cannot override run-as-principal-name element? It looks like user is verified before actual replacement (if one is even performed by deployment plan).

Any help/advice is appreciated. Thx.